# Timeslots in DayGrid View

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I need help with the fullcalendar. For the past three days I try to figure out how could I select half days in the month view.

I would like to drag a selection to create an event in the month view of my fullCalendar from let's say from 25th October 12PM to 8th November 12PM. I know I can do it in the week view with some configuration but I need it in the Month View. In another words I need timeslots in the Month View. At least two per day. I tried to change the HTML of the rendered DayTiles in the daygrid script which brought me a step further but I can´t figure out the selection and rendering of events.

```
function renderCellHtml(date, dateProfile, context, otherAttrs) {
    var dateEnv = context.dateEnv, theme = context.theme;
    var isDateValid = core.rangeContainsMarker(dateProfile.activeRange, date); // TODO: called too frequently. cache somehow.
    var classes = core.getDayClasses(date, dateProfile, context);
    classes.unshift('fc-time', theme.getClass('widgetContent'));

   // console.log(dateEnv.formatIso(dateScndHlf, { omitTime: false }));
    var dateScndHlf = new Date(date.toString());
    dateScndHlf.setTime(dateScndHlf.getTime() + (12*60*60*1000));
    return '<td class="halfdayfirst ' + classes.join(' ') + '"' +
        (isDateValid ?
            ' data-time="00:00:00" data-date="' + dateEnv.formatIso(date, { omitTime: false }) + '"' :
            '') +
        (otherAttrs ?
            ' ' + otherAttrs :
            '') +
        '></td><td class="halfdaysecond ' + classes.join(' ') + '"' +
        (isDateValid ?
            ' data-time="12:00:00" data-date="' + dateEnv.formatIso(dateScndHlf, { omitTime: false }) + '"' :
            '') +
        (otherAttrs ?
            ' ' + otherAttrs :
            '') +
        '></td>';
}
```

I'm not sure if creating a new plugin is the right way.

Maybe there is a ready solution or maybe it´s possible by some advanced configuration. Anyways, I think I am too stupid to achieve this by modifying the daygrid view. If you have an idea how to create timeslots in the Monthview, please tell me. I think I am not the only one who would like to have such a feature.

Comment: "I try to figure out how could I select half days in the month view." ...short answer, you can't. The month view has no concept of time, only days. If you need your users to do that, then provide them with an "agenda" or "timeline" view instead. If a week is too short you can always set a custom duration for the view, you are not restricted to weeks or days, those are just the defaults. Or, let them click the day in the month view and then pop up a box asking them to input the exact time via regular form fields.

Comment: FWIW you could make a feature request to get timeslots added to the month view, but I think it would be hard because the box for each day simply isn't big enough. Maybe it would have to be restricted to a minimum slot size (e.g. half a day as you suggested) but this breaks the pattern of usage in the other views where the slot duration can be set freely. I don't know if the fullCalendar developers will go for this or not. And you're right, creating your own version of the plugin is a massive PITA (both to create, and then to maintain it to keep compatibility with future fullCalendar versions).